# How to approach this tricky log problem

Tags: calculus, logarithms, elementary-functions

Consider the following equation:

$$(7 + 4\sqrt{3})^{t^2 - 5t + 5} + (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^{t^2 - 5t + 5} = 14$$

I have tried and exhausted all the methods I know of and resorted to brute force to solve this problem and got $t = 4$, $t = 1$.
However I was wondering if there was some sort of elegant solution to prove the answer algebraically.

Comment: Hint: evaluate $\left(7+4\sqrt{3}\right)\left(7-4\sqrt{3}\right)$.

Comment: Almost identical questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/74272/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1803586/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3179991/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(7%20%2B%204%5Csqrt%7B3%7D)%5E%7Bt%5E2%20-%205t%20%2B%205%7D%20%2B%20(7%20-%204%5Csqrt%7B3%7D)%5E%7Bt%5E2%20-%205t%20%2B%205%7D%20%3D%2014%24)

Comment: [Choosing a meaningful title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) is an important part of [asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/42969)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is just the equivalent of

$$(7 + 4\sqrt{3})^{p(t)} + (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^{p(t)} = 14$$

Where $p(t) = t^2 - 5t + 5$. Notice that if $p(t) = 1$ you're done since

$$(7 + 4\sqrt{3})^1 + (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^1 = 14$$

So: what are the values in $\mathbb{R}$ for which $p(t) = 1$?

(Notice that also $p(t) = -1$ works... Can you see it?)

Comment: Just in case anyone's worried a third value of $p$ would work, note the problem is equivalent to $\cosh(p(t)\operatorname{arcosh}7)=7$.

Comment: @J.G. Oh, brilliant catch! :D

Comment: @EnricoM. Really Cool!

Answer (score 9):

Setting $a(t)=(7+4\sqrt 3)^{t^2-5t+5}$ so thar $\frac 1{a(t)}=(7-4\sqrt 3)^{t^2-5t+5}$, we get
$$a(t)+\frac 1{a(t)}=14$$
and hence $a(t)=7+4\sqrt 3$ or $a(t)=7-4\sqrt 3$. So, we have
$$t^2-5t+5=1 \text{ or}\;(-1)$$
Now, solve for $t$.

Comment: Wow that is quite a beautiful solution, I am still grappling with the relationship that you used to get a+1/a. Do you have any tips to allow me to prove that?

Comment: $(7+4\sqrt{3})(7-4\sqrt{3})=1$

Comment: @yerdeth you mean solving for $a + \frac 1a = 14$ or realising that the substitution would work? If it's the former, multiply by $a$ and solve the quadratic equation. The later one is more difficult to answer- honestly, it's the first thing I saw. user376343's comment is the best thing I can provide- it's just that you need some practice with tricky applications of $a^2-b^2$ type identities.